# Is there any way to customize magnifier program on windows?

Tags: c#, zooming

I need to create or customize a magnifier. The magnifier needs to be the same as the windows 7 magnifier just differing in two things:

1) The magnifier does not follow the mouse cursor: I mean the magnifier stays static when it is zoomed in or out.

2) The mouse cursor does not go out from the magnifier view: I mean the mouse cursor can not go further from the zoomed area.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: i have play with the settings on windows 7 magnifier and the wpf extended toolkit magnifier (codeplex), but nothing has giving me the answer

Comment: You'd have to write your own magnifier.  I suggest you just use Zoomit: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx

Comment: zoomIn does not support the things i need, anywat, i was hoping to be able to customize the windows magnifier or build it by myself using c#